# Is it possible to declare generics inside Decodable model

Tags: ios, swift, codable, decodable

Here is my model class

```
struct ErrorData: Decodable {
    let code : Int
    let message : String
    let data : [ErrorDataFields]
}
```

i want to have **ErrorDataFields** to be array and object like

```
struct ErrorData: Decodable {
        let code : Int
        let message : String
        let data : [ErrorDataFields]
    }
```

AND

```
struct ErrorData: Decodable {
        let code : Int
        let message : String
        let data : ErrorDataFields
    }
```

Comment: did you try it?

Comment: I'd suggest to give it a try before posting a question, in case you face an issue you can ask about it.

Answer (score 0):

We can use a generic type with Decodable. Only thing is the generic type should also conform to Decodable.

```
struct ErrorData <T : Decodable> : Decodable {
    let code : Int
    let message : String
    let data : T
}
```